# How to make callable attribute in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I do not know how to google it, but i know what i want.

i want to make something like this

```ruby
class SchedulingManager
  attr_accessor :on_start

  def call
    on_start
  end
end

scheduling = SchedulingManager.new
scheduling.on_start do
  puts "hello"
end
```

so i want my `on_start` here to be initiate by do block style. and save it so i can call in method `call` and print hello (or do whatever code in the block).

i do not know what the name of it, i also do not know how to google it.

Kindly need your help guys, thanks

Comment: For the syntax, see [Methods – Block Argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it like this and store the block in a variable.

```
class SchedulingManager
  def on_start(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def call
    @block&.call
  end
end

scheduling = SchedulingManager.new
scheduling.on_start do
  puts "hello"
end

scheduling.call
#=> hello
```